# Dynamic Rate Limiting Algorithm

Tags: python, string, logging, limit

I'm trying to figure out how to group client request on a rate/minute basis, meaning is has to account for numerous 60-second windows for each client.

```
def solution(A,Y)
      # Where "A" is the input and "Y" is the given rate limit
```

The input A is an array of strings with the format `<client> <timestamp>`

For example, given a limit of 3 and the following logs:

```
"java 0"
"java 15"
"java 59"
"java 60"
"java 120"
"java 240"
"python 0"
"python 15"
"python 45"
"python 125"
```

The function would return `["java 6", "python 4"]`

But what the code actually has to do it group on a per/minute basis meaning

`java 0-59: 3 request`
`java 60-119: 1 request`
`java 120-179: 0 request`

And then adding up all of the request for each client throughout the entire log.

How would you, using Python 3.6, account for how many request a sent through per minute for each client?

Comment: "... what the program is actually..", what program?

Comment: Show the code you have implemented which gives you `["java 6", "python 4"]`